# Yarn of hadoop 3.1.1 can't schedule GPU resource

Tags: hadoop, gpu, hadoop3

I have installed Hadoop 3.1.1 which supports GPU resources.  And I configured it according to the [official document](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/UsingGpus.html) . However, when I run the word count program with a 800M+ file, the GPU finding resource never are used; at the same time the program works well using memory and vcores(CPU).

All the Prerequisites [listed in official document](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/UsingGpus.html) are met: GPU device,CUDA,cgoup etc. GPU works well when I run the docker but Hadoop 3.

Follow are the configuration files:

Resource Type: 
[image]

capacity-scheduler.xml,other property as default
[image]

yarn-site.xml
[image]

container-executor.cfg
[image]

Comment: ok, I will use it next question. thx.